# specifying the admin to no full access in the ACL (access control list)

Tags: windows, acl

I was working in the security tab found in the property of a disk. then I decided to change the access of users account to no full access, and by accident I include myself , and right now I can not access to this disk or even change the settings of the security because it says I am not allowed to access this disk or change the settings even as  administrator account

when I did this, I expected to exclude me, but after I realized that is even applied to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't removed "Full Control" for "System" and the commandline is your friend:

Get "PsExec.exe" from Microsoft Sysinternals (easy to find with your preferred search engine).

From a cmd-console which is launched with local admin privileges, run this command:

```
start PsExec.exe -i -s cmd
```

This command will launch another cmd-console which runs as "System". As a proof it worked, execute:

```
set username
```

... within this "System"-console. This should return the computername.

Within this "System"-console you can use commandline tools like the Windows built-in "icacls.exe" to restore file system permissions for administrators and users.